# Tengo este error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style') y no puedo resolverlo

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

Estoy haciendo un peruqeño ejercicio que mediante eentos de teclado una pequeña pelotita tiene que moverse dentro de un div, los movimeintos son controlados por switchs y al final intento añadir un valor Css translate mediante la propiedad 'style', al momento de correr el documento me aparece:

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')"

Haciendo referencia a la propiedad style, tengo la sintáxis bien pero no entiendo el porqué del error.

Este es el código HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css">
<title>Keyboard Events</title>
</head>
  <body>
    <header class="header">
    <h1>Keyboard Events.</h1>
</header>

<main>
    <section id="seccion1" class="section">
        <article class="stage">
            <div class="ball">
                
            </div>
        </article>
    </section>

</main>

<script src="./main.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Y este es el código JavaScript:

```
const d = document;
let x = 0; 
let y = 0;

export function moveBall(event, ball, stage) { 

const $ball = d.querySelector('ball'); 
const $stage = d.querySelector('stage'); 


console.log(event.keyCode);
console.log(event.key);



switch (event.keyCode) {
    case 37:


        x--; 
        
        break;

    case 38: 

 
       y--;   
        
        break;

    case 39: 

     
       x++; 
        
        break;

    case 40: 

   
        y++; 
        
        break;

    default:
        break;
}

$ball.style.transform = `translate (${x * 10}px, ${y * 10}px)`; 
}
```

Comment: Hola Marco, bienvenido, podrías cambiar **<div class="ball">** por **<div id="ball">** y **const $ball = d.querySelector('ball');** por **const $ball = d.getElementById('ball');**, a ver si funciona, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.

Comment: El nombramiento de variables o constantes en `JS` no requiere anteponerle el símbolo **$**. Esto es usado en `PHP` mas no en `JS`.

Comment: ERROR RESUELTO, AGRADEZCO LAS RESPUESTAS DE LOS QUE SE TOMARON LA MOLESTIA EN APORTAR :).

Answer (score 0):

El error es de semantica en el uso del selector, es que d.querySelector no encuentra 'ball' porque el selector para saber que tiene que buscar una clase tiene que anteponer un '.', entonces tenes que usar d.querySelector('.ball'), igual si el selector busca un elemento por id utiliza '#', si solo lo dejas como 'ball' buscaria un tag de html que se llame [ball] que igual esta incorrecto en la semantica